# iOS 8 + interactive transition + nav bar shown = broken?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

We're trying to add an interactive transition in our app between two views. We can make it work fine on iOS 7, or on iOS 8 *without the navigation bar being shown*. But, we need to have a navbar shown. To demonstrate (some of) the problems we're having, I created a small prototype which the screenshots show below. I tried UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition but found enough posts claiming that it has problems that I got rid of it.

**Source**: https://github.com/xaphod/TransitionBugger

Here is what it looks like on iOS 8, with a navigationController, but the nav bar is set NOT to show in the Storyboard: it works fine

[image: Works on iOS 8 without navbar]

Here's the exact same thing but with the nav bar shown. When there's a navbar, then somehow there are no touches received in the toViewcontroller after the transition completes (notice how the UIButton doesn't get a touch event):

[image: Broken on iOS 8 with navbar]

And perhaps telling is that the navbar appears to be in a broken state. Watch what happens if I background the app and go back into it - the navbar state changes: the "Item" bar button changes to "Back" only once the app comes to foreground. Why is that happening?

[image: navbar changes when app backgrounded]

I have read at least 12 posts on stackoverflow, objc.io, and elsewhere with lots of suggested solutions and tutorials etc. We have tried them all, including these threads:

["From View Controller" disappears using UIViewControllerContextTransitioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338700/from-view-controller-disappears-using-uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning/25655575#25655575) (another problem our main app is having)

[Touches not recognized after custom transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300050/touches-not-recognized-after-custom-transition)

... but **they only work when there is no navbar shown**.

How can we make interactive transitions work with a navbar on iOS 8 ? All help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up moving away from using the UINavigationControllerDelegate approach, because we needed the transitioned view to cover the tab bar too. When we moved to the modal fullscreen transitioning approach, this problem was solved.